# Flutter : Change toolbar color in both Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to flutter, Just trying to create a page where top portion has a red background( stacked) and some text content above it. I want to extend the background colour to the toolbar as well. tried with `AnnotatedRegion` but it didn't work as expected.Image is attached for reference where toolbar still has a white background, but wanted Red color.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 500,
                    height: 350,
                    // alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: mainTextStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Hey Test"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **AppBar** to the scaffold and **backgroundColor** to red

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: //widget
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `SafeArea` widget with `Container` widget and set `color` in the `Container` widget

Like this

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.green, /* Set your status bar color here */
    child: SafeArea(child: Container(
      /* Add your Widget here */
    )),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This adds colour to the entire screen which is not what I wanted. I just need background color for top portion